# Use Lowercase Roman Page Numbering with spanish babel

Tags: page-numbering, spanish

I'm creating a document where I need the `\frontmatter` to be enumerated with lowercase Roman numbers, but I'm getting uppercase numbers due to the command `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`, can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Please always show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) instead of a single command only. (See the link about how and why).

Comment: They are small caps, not uppercase. The reason is explained here: https://texnia.com/spanish2.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`babel-spanish`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-spanish) defines modifiers for all the extended features, e.g., `es-lcroman` to switch of the upper case feature for Roman numbers:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\lipsum
\mainmatter
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, using the options means, that no lowercase Roman numbers will be changed to uppercase any longer. It does not mean, that explicit uppercase Roman numbers using `\Roman` will be changed to lowercase.

See the [manual of `babel-spanish`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/spanish/spanish.pdf) for more information. Unfortunately it is available in Spanish only, so I cannot read it myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro, it solved my situation!!!!